# What is different between a Cat IIIA, Cat IIIB, and Cat IIIC ILS approach?

Tags: approach, icao, ils

In terms of aircraft equipment, approach minimums, procedural differences, and anything else relevant, how do the 3 types of a Cat III ILS differ from one another?

Comment: You may narrow your question as a simple search on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system#ILS_categories) gives lots of information and [great references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system#cite_note-Airbus-7) to answer a significant part of your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### ICAO and FAA CAT III definitions

A CAT III operation is a precision approach at lower than CAT II minima. Sub-categories are listed below.

- A category III A approach is a precision instrument approach and landing
  with no decision height or a decision height lower than 100ft (30m) and a runway
  visual range not less than 700ft (200m).
- A category III B approach is a precision approach and landing with no
  decision height or a decision height lower than 50ft (15m) and a runway visual
  range less than 700ft (200m), but not less than 150ft (50m).
- A category III C approach is a precision approach and landing with no
  decision height and no runway visual range limitation.

*I've omitted the JAA definitions.

Source [Airbus Flight Operations Support documentation](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/1480.pdf).

---

#### FAA Reference Material

The below links are to comprehensive FAA publications covering the areas as titled.

[FAA AC120-29 for CAT I/II](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC120-29A.pdf).

[FAA AC120-28 for CAT III](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/120.28C.pdf).

*Thanks [@Sports Racer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/2341/sports-racer) for the comment with links to these documents.*

Comment: Also see FAA AC120-29 for CAT I/II http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC120-29A.pdf and FAA AC120-28 for CAT III http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/120.28C.pdf

Comment: It might not hurt to move them into your answer. Sometimes things in comments get lost.

Comment: It may be worth to note than in Europe CATIIIb is 75m-200m RVR, and DH <100ft. CATIIIa is the same as FAA in Europe. [EU-OPS-1 page 81, Aerodrome operating minima, (g) Precision approach — Category III operations](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2008:254:0001:0238:EN:PDF)

Answer (score 4):

From: AC 120-118
https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_120-118.pdf

CAT I (FAA)
An instrument approach operation with a minimum descent altitude (MDA), decision altitude (DA), or decision height (DH) not lower than 200 feet (60 m) and with either a visibility not less than ½ SM, or a Runway Visual Range (RVR) not less than 1800 feet (550 m).
CAT I (ICAO)
Any precision approach and landing operation with a DA/H of 60 m (200 feet) or higher and with a minimum visibility of 550 m RVR or greater will be termed a Standard CAT I operation.

CAT II (FAA) 
A precision instrument approach operation with a DH lower than 150 feet but not lower than 100 feet and a RVR not less than 1000 feet.
CAT II (ICAO) 
Standard CAT II operations are made to a DA/H below 60 m (200 feet), but not lower than 30 m (100 feet), with associated RVRs ranging from 550m (1800 feet) to 300 m (1000 feet).

CAT III (FAA) 
A precision instrument approach and landing operation with a DH lower than 100 feet (30 m) or no DH, or a RVR less than 1000 feet (300 m).
CAT IIIa (ICAO) 
A precision instrument approach and landing operation with a DH lower than 30 m (100 feet) or no DH and an RVR not less than 175 m (600 feet). 
CAT IIIb (ICAO) 
A precision instrument approach and landing operation with a DH lower than 15m (50 feet) or no DH and an RVR lower than 175m (600 feet) but not less than 50m (200 feet). 
CAT IIIc (ICAO) 
A precision instrument approach and landing with no RVR limitations.

Answer (score 3):

Most recent European Law (so at least applicable in Europe):

> A "type A instrument approach operation” means an instrument approach
> operation with a minimum descent  height or decision height at or
> above 75 m (250 ft);
>
> A "type B instrument approach operation” means an instrument approach
> operation with a decision height below 75 m (250 ft). Type B
> instrument approach operations are categorised as follows:
>
> 1. Category I (CAT I): a decision height not lower than 60 m (200 ft) and with either a visibility not less  than 800 m or a runway visual
>    range not less than 550 m;
> 2. Category II (CAT II): a decision height lower than 60 m (200 ft), but not lower than 30 m (100 ft) and  a runway visual range not less
>    than 300 m;
> 3. Category IIIA (CAT IIIA): a decision height lower than 30 m (100 ft) or no decision height and a runway  visual range not less than 175
>    m;
> 4. Category IIIB (CAT IIIB): a decision height lower than 15 m (50 ft) or no decision height and a runway  visual range less than 175 m, but
>    not less than 50 m;
> 5. Category IIIC (CAT IIIC): no decision height and no runway visual range limitation;’.

https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32018R0401&from=EN

Answer (score 2):

- Cat III A 600 feet (180 meters) Runway Visible Range (RVR)
- CAT III B 150 feet (46 meters) RVR
- CAT III C zero visibility

No decision height in any CAT III approach (CAT II is 100' and CAT I is 200')

Comment: A Cat IIIA approach can have a 50' DH for operators that need one.  Not sure how wide or narrow that set of operators is, though.

Comment: Also please note that specifications differ here between FAA and ICAO. These figures are FAA-figures (which may very will be what the OP wanted)

Comment: Quite. So I don't appreciate the negative vote!

Comment: You may consider editing the answer to a more readable format.

Comment: There's also the Alert Height, Read more in FAA AC120-28. http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/120.28C.pdf